# Replacing old C style arrays with modern C++ STL data structures

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, stdarray, construct

I implemented a simple class for n-body simulations in C++. However, the class uses a lot of old C style arrays which I want to replace with data structures that the STL offers.

Here is the relevant part of my code that I want to improve:

```
struct Particle{
    double m;           // mass
    double x[DIM];      // position
    double v[DIM];      // velocity
    double F[DIM];      // force 
};

class Nbody {
    private:
        const unsigned int n;           // number of particles
        const double dt;                // step size
        const double t_max;             // max simulation time
        std::vector<Particle> p;
    public:
        ~Nbody(){};
        Nbody(unsigned int n_, double dt_, double t_max_);
};

Nbody::Nbody(unsigned int n_, double dt_, double t_max_)
    : n{n_}, dt{dt_}, t_max{t_max_} {
    p = new std::vector<Particle> [n];
}
```

I tried to use `std::vector<Particle>`. But how do I in this case initialize `n` particles correctly? My current approach does not work and the compiler throws many errors. How do I do it correctly?

Comment: What did the old C style arrays look like?

Comment: Have you tried `: n{n_}, dt{dt_}, t_max{t_max_}, p{n} {`?

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco I used `Particle *p = new Particle[n];` in the private part of my class and was told that this is really bad.

Comment: For the same reasons you should consider replacing the arrays in `Particle` with `std::array<double, DIM>`

Comment: @Samuel did you ask why it was bad?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are `x`, `v`, and `F` in `Particle` being represented as arrays? It's like a single particle can have multiple positions, velocities, and forces.

Comment: @Roy2511 First I placed `Particle *p = new Particle[n];` inside `private` which would lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco I guess it's like x,y,z ; Vx,Vy,Vz; Fx,Fy,Fz ... Each particle's representation in space, the instantaneous velocity vector it has and force vector applied on it

Comment: @Roy2511 Ah, good point. Might be better if that was explicitly three different space variables rather than an array then, unless this is for n-dimensional particles?

Comment: Careful with uniform initialisation and `std::vector`: `std::vector<int> v{1, 7}` will *not* produce a vector with two elements, but one with 7, as there's a constructor overload accepting two parameters. This is the most important reason I *personally* (feel free to be of opposite opinion!) consider UI broken (there are quite a few minor other examples). `std::vector<int> v(1, 7)` vs. `std::vector<int> v({1, 7})` is just so much clearer (and yes, initialiser lists *are* great...).

Comment: @super Can you explain why? Should I also consider taking `std::vector()`?

Comment: @Samuel For a dynamic array use `std::vector`, for a static array use `std::array`. Take a look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and you will see some of the handy member function it's equipped with. It also has overloads for a lot of free functions like `std::begin` ect. And what makes it great is that it's still just a static array, nothing more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p` is not a pointer. `p` is declared as a vector.

Rewrite the constructor definition like

```
Nbody::Nbody(unsigned int n_, double dt_, double t_max_)
    : n{n_}, dt{dt_}, t_max{t_max_}, p( n_ ) {
}
```

In this case the vector `p` is initialized as a vector having n elements that are value initialized.

Also in the definition of the structure `Particle` you could substitute the arrays to objects of the type `std::array<double, DIM>`. Also it is better to make the constant `DIM` either as enumerator of the structure or as a static data member of the structure/

Comment: I'm happy about you falling back to classic initialisation (`p(n)`), but intermixing styles is in my eyes even worse than the (broken) uniform initialisation...

Comment: @Aconcagua Where do you see the intermixing style?

Answer (score 2):

`new std::vector<Particle> [n]` dynamically allocates an array of `n` empty vectors and produces a pointer to the first one.
That is not the same as a vector with `n` elements.

You should use the initialiser list:

```
Nbody::Nbody(unsigned int n_, double dt_, double t_max_)
    : n{n_}, dt{dt_}, t_max{t_max_}, p{n_}
{
    // Empty.
}
```

Assuming that `n` tracks the number of particles, you can get rid of it and use `p.size()` instead.

Initialisation of the particles themselves should be added to `Particle`.

```
struct Particle{
    double mass = 0.0;
    double position[DIM] = {};
    double velocity[DIM] = {};
    double force[DIM] = {}; 
};
```

or

```
struct Particle{
    double mass = 0.0;
    std::array<double, DIM> position;
    std::array<double, DIM> velocity;
    std::array<double, DIM> force; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Why did you set the mass to zero? To prevent bugs?

Comment: @Samuel A good rule of thumb is to always initialise everything, and zero seemed like a reasonable default mass. Use some other value if that makes more sense to you. Just don't leave it uninitialised.

Comment: Does using `{}` initialize the particles with zeros?

Comment: @Samuel Yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

To change the size of a vector, you can use:

```
p.resize(n);
```

All new elements will be default-constructed, which in this case means they will contain garbage values.